# Accordion with single scrollbar for all its sub tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to create a jquery based UI, in which I will have the below html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

    <style type="text/css">
        div .content
        {
            border: 2px solid black;
            background-color: White;
        }

    div.content::-webkit-scrollbar{
  display:none;
   }
   #container::-webkit-scrollbar{
  display:none;
   }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" id="btnPopup">
        Show Popup</button>
    <div id="container" style="display: none; border: 2px solid green; background-color: Blue;">
        <h3>
            DISTRIBUTION</h3>
        <div class="content">
            <p>
                Using jQuery UI Resizable I'm trying to prevent resizing based on various rules.
                The built-in containment feature doesn't seem to work properly with absolutely positioned
                elements, and I would need something more flexible than that anyway. Having something
                like this: Using jQuery UI Resizable I'm trying to prevent resizing based on various
                rules. The built-in containment feature doesn't seem to work properly with absolutely
                positioned elements, and I would need something more flexible than that anyway.
                Having something like this: Using jQuery UI Resizable I'm trying to prevent resizing
                based on various rules. The built-in containment feature doesn't seem to work properly
                with absolutely positioned elements, and I would need something more flexible than
                that anyway. Having something like this: Using jQuery UI Resizable I'm trying to
                prevent resizing based on various rules. The built-in containment feature doesn't
                seem to work properly with absolutely positioned elements, and I would need something
                more flexible than that anyway. Having something like this: Using jQuery UI Resizable
                I'm trying to prevent resizing based on various rules. The built-in containment
                feature doesn't seem to work properly with absolutely positioned elements, and I
                would need something more flexible than that anyway. Having something like this:
                Using jQuery UI Resizable I'm trying to prevent resizing based on various rules.
                The built-in containment feature doesn't seem to work properly with absolutely positioned
                elements, and I would need something more flexible than that anyway. Having something
                like this: Using jQuery UI Resizable I'm trying to prevent resizing based on various
                rules. The built-in containment feature doesn't seem to work properly with absolutely
                positioned elements, and I would need something more flexible than that anyway.
                Having something like this: Using jQuery UI Resizable I'm trying to prevent resizing
                based on various rules. The built-in containment feature doesn't seem to work properly
                with absolutely positioned elements, and I would need something more flexible than
                that anyway. Having something like this:
            </p>
        </div>
        <h3>
            EXCEPTION</h3>
        <div class="content">
            <p>
                Using jQuery UI Resizable I'm trying to prevent resizing based on various rules.
                The built-in containment feature doesn't seem to work properly with absolutely positioned
                elements, and I would need something more flexible than that anyway. Having something
                like this:</p>
            <p>
                Using jQuery UI Resizable I'm trying to prevent resizing based on various rules.
                The built-in containment feature doesn't seem to work properly with absolutely positioned
                elements, and I would need something more flexible than that anyway. Having something
                like this:</p>
        </div>
        <h3>
            ERROR</h3>
        <div class="content">
            <p>
                Using jQuery UI Resizable I'm trying to prevent resizing based on various rules.
                The built-in containment feature doesn't seem to work properly with absolutely positioned
                elements, and I would need something more flexible than that anyway. Having something
                like this:</p>
        </div>
        <h3>
            MY NOTES</h3>
        <div class="content">
            <p>
                Using jQuery UI Resizable I'm trying to prevent resizing based on various rules.
                The built-in containment feature doesn't seem to work properly with absolutely positioned
                elements, and I would need something more flexible than that anyway. Having something
                like this:</p>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#container").accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        heightStyle: "content",
        beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {
            // The accordion believes a panel is being opened
            if (ui.newHeader[0]) {
                var currHeader = ui.newHeader;
                var currContent = currHeader.next('.ui-accordion-content');
                // The accordion believes a panel is being closed
            } else {
                var currHeader = ui.oldHeader;
                var currContent = currHeader.next('.ui-accordion-content');
            }
            // Since we've changed the default behavior, this detects the actual status
            var isPanelSelected = currHeader.attr('aria-selected') == 'true';

            // Toggle the panel's header
            currHeader.toggleClass('ui-corner-all', isPanelSelected).toggleClass('accordion-header-active ui-state-active ui-corner-top', !
isPanelSelected).attr('aria-selected', ((!isPanelSelected).toString()));

            // Toggle the panel's icon
            currHeader.children('.ui-icon').toggleClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-e', isPanelSelected).toggleClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-s', !isPanelSelected);

            // Toggle the panel's content
            currContent.toggleClass('accordion-content-active', !isPanelSelected)
            if (isPanelSelected) { currContent.slideUp(); } else { currContent.slideDown(); }


            return false; // Cancel the default action
        }
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".content").css('max-height', $("#container").height() - 150);

    });

    $(document).delegate("#btnPopup", "click", function () {

        $("#container").dialog({
            title: "jQuery Modal Dialog Popup",
            resizable: false,
            width: 800,
            maxHeight: 800
            //minHeight: 250,
            //minWidth: 500,
            //resize: function (event, ui) {
            //    $(".content").css('max-height', ($("#container").height() - 250));
            //}
        });
        return false;
    });


//    $(document).bind('wheel mousewheel', function (e) {
//      
//        if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0) {
//           
//        }
//        else {
//            k = h = 0;
//            $("div.content").each(function () {
//                if ($(this).is(":focus")) {
//                    h = k;
//                }
//                k++;
//            });
//            if ($('.content')[h] != undefined && h != (k - 1)) {
//                if ($('#container').children('div.content').eq(h).scrollTop() + $('#container').children('div.content').eq(h).innerHeight() >=
//$('.content')[h].scrollHeight) {
//                   
//                    if (!($('div.content').eq(h + 1).prev('h3').hasClass('ui-state-active'))) {
//                        var totalDiv = $('div.content').length;
//                        var h3Height = $('h3').height();

//                      

//                        $("#container").accordion({ active: h + 1 });

//                        var f = $('h3.ui-state-active').length;
//                        //if (f != 1) {
//                        $('div.content').each(function () {
//                            if ($(this).css('display') == 'block')
//                                $(this).css('max-height', ((parseInt($('#container').css('max-height')) / f) - (h3Height * (totalDiv + 1))));
//                        });
//                        $('div.content').eq(h + 1).focus();
//                      
//                    }
//                }
//            }
//           
//        }
//        });


    (function ($) {
        $.fn.hasScrollBar = function () {
            return this.get(0).scrollHeight > this.height();
        }
    })(jQuery);

//    $(function () {
//        $(".content").bind('scroll', function () {           
//            if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
//                //alert('end reached');
//                $(this).next('h3').click();
//                $(this).next('div.content').focus();
//            }
//        });
//    })




    $('div.content').bind('mousewheel', function (e) {
        if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) {
            // $(this).text('scrolling up !');
        }
        else {
            //            if ($('div.content').hasScrollBar()) {

            //                if ($('div.content').scrollTop() == ($('div.content p').height() - $('div.content').height())) {
            //                    alert('end!');
            //                }
            //            }    


            if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {

                //alert('end reached');



                $(this).next('h3').click();
                $(this).prev('h3').click()
               // $(this).next('div.content').attr('display', 'block');
                $(this).blur();
                $(this).next('div.content').focus();


            }


        }
    });




//    $('.content').bind('mousewheel', function (e) {
//        if ($('div.content').hasScrollBar()) {
//            $(this).delegate(".content", "scroll", function () {
//                if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
//                    //alert('end reached');
//                    $(this).next('h3').click();
//                    $(this).next('div.content').focus();
//                }
//            });
//        }
//        else {
//            $(this).next('h3').click();
//            $(this).next('div.content').focus();
//        }
//    });

    $(document).delegate("h3", "click", function () {
        var totalDiv = $('div.content').length;
        var h3Height = $('h3').height();
        var f = $('h3.ui-state-active').length;
        //        if (!($(this).hasClass('ui-state-active'))) {

        if (f != 1) {
            $('div.content').each(function () {
                if ($(this).css('display') == 'block')
                    $(this).css('max-height', ((parseInt($('#container').css('max-height')) / f) - (h3Height * (totalDiv + 1))));
            });
        }      
    });
</script>
</html>
```

The above html displays an accordion.
What I need to do us have a single scrollbar for the entire accordion content which will work like follows:
When 1st div scrolling is reached till end, second div will open up, on completion of second div scroll(if no scroll is present then too the same thing will happen), 3rd div will open up.
Now, this goes with scrolling downwards, the same should work when user scrolls upwards.

Please let me know the solution which has to be applied to implement the above type of functionality.

Comment: Hi, does anybody have any idea about this, really its urgent.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("#container").accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        heightStyle: "content",
        beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {
            // The accordion believes a panel is being opened
          var currHeader ;
          var currContent;
            if (ui.newHeader[0]) {
                 currHeader = ui.newHeader;
                 currContent = currHeader.next('.ui-accordion-content');
                // The accordion believes a panel is being closed
            } else {
                currHeader = ui.oldHeader;
               currContent = currHeader.next('.ui-accordion-content');
            }
            // Since we've changed the default behavior, this detects the actual status
            var isPanelSelected = currHeader.attr('aria-selected') == 'true';

            // Toggle the panel's header
            currHeader.toggleClass('ui-corner-all', isPanelSelected).toggleClass('accordion-header-active ui-state-active ui-corner-top', !
isPanelSelected).attr('aria-selected', ((!isPanelSelected).toString()));

            // Toggle the panel's icon
            currHeader.children('.ui-icon').toggleClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-e', isPanelSelected).toggleClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-s', !isPanelSelected);

            // Toggle the panel's content
            currContent.toggleClass('accordion-content-active', !isPanelSelected);
            if (isPanelSelected) { currContent.slideUp(); } else { currContent.slideDown(); }


            return false; // Cancel the default action
        }
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".content").css('max-height', $("#container").height() - 150);

    });

    $(document).delegate("#btnPopup", "click", function () {

        $("#container").dialog({
            title: "jQuery Modal Dialog Popup",
            resizable: false,
            width: 800,
            maxHeight: 800
            //minHeight: 250,
            //minWidth: 500,
            //resize: function (event, ui) {
            //    $(".content").css('max-height', ($("#container").height() - 250));
            //}
        });
        return false;
    });


//    $(document).bind('wheel mousewheel', function (e) {
//      
//        if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0) {
//           
//        }
//        else {
//            k = h = 0;
//            $("div.content").each(function () {
//                if ($(this).is(":focus")) {
//                    h = k;
//                }
//                k++;
//            });
//            if ($('.content')[h] != undefined && h != (k - 1)) {
//                if ($('#container').children('div.content').eq(h).scrollTop() + $('#container').children('div.content').eq(h).innerHeight() >=
//$('.content')[h].scrollHeight) {
//                   
//                    if (!($('div.content').eq(h + 1).prev('h3').hasClass('ui-state-active'))) {
//                        var totalDiv = $('div.content').length;
//                        var h3Height = $('h3').height();

//                      

//                        $("#container").accordion({ active: h + 1 });

//                        var f = $('h3.ui-state-active').length;
//                        //if (f != 1) {
//                        $('div.content').each(function () {
//                            if ($(this).css('display') == 'block')
//                                $(this).css('max-height', ((parseInt($('#container').css('max-height')) / f) - (h3Height * (totalDiv + 1))));
//                        });
//                        $('div.content').eq(h + 1).focus();
//                      
//                    }
//                }
//            }
//           
//        }
//        });


    (function ($) {
        $.fn.hasScrollBar = function () {
            return this.get(0).scrollHeight > this.height();
        };
    })(jQuery);

//    $(function () {
//        $(".content").bind('scroll', function () {           
//            if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
//                //alert('end reached');
//                $(this).next('h3').click();
//                $(this).next('div.content').focus();
//            }
//        });
//    })




    $('div.content').bind('mousewheel', function (e) {

        if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta == 120) {
            // $(this).text('scrolling up !');
         //alert("up scrolling");
          try{

            var x=$(this).prev('h3');
            var y=x.prev('div.content');
            $('.content').attr('display', 'none');
             $(this).prev('div.content').focus();
 if ( $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
            y.prev('h3').click();
            x.click();
 }
            x.prev('div.content').attr('display', 'block');


        }catch(err){alert(err.message);}
        }
        else {

            if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {

                //alert('end reached');



                $(this).next('h3').click();
                $(this).prev('h3').click();
               // $(this).next('div.content').attr('display', 'block');
                $(this).blur();
                $(this).next('div.content').focus();


            }


        }
    });




//    $('.content').bind('mousewheel', function (e) {
//        if ($('div.content').hasScrollBar()) {
//            $(this).delegate(".content", "scroll", function () {
//                if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
//                    //alert('end reached');
//                    $(this).next('h3').click();
//                    $(this).next('div.content').focus();
//                }
//            });
//        }
//        else {
//            $(this).next('h3').click();
//            $(this).next('div.content').focus();
//        }
//    });

    $(document).delegate("h3", "click", function () {
        var totalDiv = $('div.content').length;
        var h3Height = $('h3').height();
        var f = $('h3.ui-state-active').length;
        //        if (!($(this).hasClass('ui-state-active'))) {

        if (f != 1) {
            $('div.content').each(function () {
                if ($(this).css('display') == 'block')
                    $(this).css('max-height', ((parseInt($('#container').css('max-height')) / f) - (h3Height * (totalDiv + 1))));
            });
        }      
    });
```

Here is the updated javascript which will also work when you scroll up i.e it will close the current pane and open the previous pane.  Here is the working JSBIN demo http://jsbin.com/viwojelico/2/edit?html,js

Comment: There are no such errors showing up in the code above when I run it through vs2010

Comment: visual studio wont show those errors try this there you will come to know http://jsbin.com/xabuxolewe/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I have modified the code to remove the errors and warnings, but cannot see ny o/p. I recommend, please try it in VS itself, coz o/p can be seen there

Comment: Thanks for the update :) Do you have any clue about a single scrollbar for all four divs which will work in accordance and in consecutive manner i.e scroll 1st div then when first div ends the same scroll bar will scroll the second div and so on. I just needed to confirm if this is actually possible or not?

Comment: as of now i cant say but may be it is possible. will have to see and try then only i can say anything.

Comment: was busy somewhere since last week. Today was looking into it. What you want is that there should be a common scroll bar for the division containing the accordion and the panes can have their separate scroll bars and the common scroll bar should adapt to this down and up scroll functionality. Or there should be just one single scroll bar and that should only serve the purpose.

Comment: please refer this link and run it in IE if possible http://jsbin.com/feyorixade   This is what I have been able to achieve till now, but need to have the scrolls fixed since they are not yet crisp in its working. So, the eg show what I want is a dingle scroll controlling multiple collapsible divs consecutively i.e. on scroll in 1st div, when scroll reaches bottom, 2nd div expands, when 2nd scroll reaches bottom, 3rd div expands, and so on..Also the height of entire thing should be fixed like in eg, it should not go below the entire screen.

Comment: i saw your demo. i understood what you want. It should be like a single scroll bar that should scroll through all four divisions one after the other. will have to look a bit deeper into it will update as soon i get some workaround. because will have to go through your code as well.

Comment: sorry buddy busy with my job not able to look into.