# Multiple divs scroll with single scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have 4 divs nested within a parent div, all of which are scrollable. 
What I need to modify in this is that, the child divs should be scrollable but, all these child divs will have a single scrollbar in common which will operate on child divs one by one as user scrolls down i.e. when user finishes scrolling the 1st div, focus shifts to 2nd div and it starts getting scrolled till end, once 2nd div scroll reaches end, the focus shifts to 3rd div and so on.

Also note, the above divs are in the form of jquery accordion i.e. in collapsible form, thus initially only 1st div will be open and as per the scrolling and focus shifting due to scroll, the next div will open and get scrolled

Please let me know how to implement this functionality.

Comment: can you show what you have so far and/or a js fiddle? you'd need a javascript solution for this

Comment: Please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30587192/accordion-with-single-scrollbar-for-all-its-sub-tabs

Comment: The question you have linked to doesn't have a selected answer??

Comment: Why did you post the same question twice?

Comment: @atmd - this question was not answered, but it has the code which I have described in above question

Comment: @chiapa - My previous question was not answered so I re-posted it in theory format. I need to get this functionality implemented asap.

Comment: you previous question had a suggested answer, you said those issues where fixed, was the code updated? was a jsfiddle made? I'd suggest you update that question and reproduce the issue in a jsfiddle so we can help you out

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle. It would be easier for us to check and suggest possible solution.

Comment: You shouldn't post the same question on a different format. It's a duplicate question. You should edit the original one by adding details and improving in any way you see fit and hope for answers. The more detailed your question, more probability you have of seeing it answered. For example, just creating a fiddle will attract many more helpers

Comment: @atmd - please check this link http://jsbin.com/xabuxolewe/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: your jsfiddle is full of error, as per your first question

Comment: The errors have been rectified - http://jsbin.com/xabuxolewe/1/edit?html,js,output   Please refer the link click the show button in output window, u will c the results